# Locking Windows hosts file by password or something

Tags: hosts-file, internet-filter

I want to stop distractions like facebook.com

So I put

```
127.0.01 facebook.com
```

It works and I do facebook less. But still I sometimes access hosts again and erases it to do facebook.

Can I lock opening or editing hosts file by password or something? I will let someone else keep that password.

Comment: The only reason the hosts file would change is if you had security software doing it.  By default the file already requires an Adminitrator to open and save it.

Comment: @Ramhound This is my home PC so I am the administrator. So I have to set some password for administrator to prevent myself from editing hosts? And that's the only way to do it?

Comment: Use a normal restricted `User`.  This way when you modify the file you have to elevate the action which will require your `Administrator` account's password.

Answer (score 3):

Anything you do to the hosts file can be undone.  You would have to give up your admin rights.  to the machine.

You could block Facebook at the router level.  You could then change the password there and that would prevent you from accessing Facebook.  That is, unless you have physical access to the router, then you could just reset it.

The solution is simple.  Learn self control.

Comment: the most simple things in life are the difficult ones to master. I'm  also always on superuser all the time.... Plus coming back to the question - if the user is using his laptop (assumption) elsewhere and not under his router - that still gives the user the access to FB. The hosts file I guess is the better option